# Number of ways of putting n indistinguishable balls into k indistinguishable groups.

Tags: combinatorics

http://www.campusgate.co.in/2011/10/permutations-balls-and-boxes-related.html

Can someone explain how the recurrence table for Case 4 has been obtained ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the table contains three errors: the correct total for $N=5$ is $7$, not $8$; the entry for $N=6,K=3$ should be $3$, not $4$; and the total for $N=6$ should be $11$, not $12$.

The entry in row $n$, column $k$, is $p_k(n)$, the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $n$ into $k$ parts. It’s the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of $k$ positive integers if the order of the integers doesn’t matter. Taking $n=6$, for example, we can write it as the sum of $3$ positive integers in $3$ ways: $4+1+1,3+2+1$, and $2+2+2$. In the balls and boxes model these correspond to putting $4$ balls in one box and $1$ ball into each of the other two boxes; putting $3$ balls into one box, $2$ into another, and $1$ into the third; and putting $2$ balls into each box. The indistiniguishability of the boxes is reflected in the fact that we don’t care about the order of the summands: $3+2+1$ is the same partition as $2+1+3$.

There is no nice closed form for these restricted partition numbers, but they do satisfy the recurrence

$$p_k(n)=p_{k-1}(n-1)+p_k(n-k)\;,\tag{1}$$

with $p_k(n)=0$ for $k>n$, $p_n(n)=1$ for $n\ge 0$, and $p_0(n)=0$ for $n>0$, so the table can be extended quite easily. It’s clear that $p_0(n)=0$ if $n>0$: you can’t put a positive number of balls into $0$ boxes. It’s also clear that $p_n(n)=1$ if $n\ge 1$: the only way to put $n$ balls into $n$ boxes is to put $1$ ball into each box. It’s convenient to let $p_0(0)=1$ as well. The recurrence $(1)$ is also fairly easy to justify. Suppose that I distribute $n$ balls to $k$ boxes. There are two possibilities: some box contains only $1$ ball, or every box contains at least $2$ balls.

- If some box contains $1$ ball, throw away that box and ball, and you have left a distribution of $n-1$ balls into $k-1$ boxes. Conversely, if you start with a distribution of $n-1$ balls into $k-1$ boxes, you can add a box with a ball in it to get a distribution of $n$ balls into $k$ boxes, at least one of which contains only $1$ ball. Thus, there are $p_{k-1}(n-1)$ distributions of this type.
- If every box contains at least $2$ balls, throw away $1$ ball from each box, and you have left a distribution of $n-k$ balls into $k$ boxes. Conversely, if you start with a distribution of $n-k$ balls into $k$ boxes, you can add a ball to each box to get a distribution of $n$ balls into $k$ boxes in which every box contains at least $2$ balls. Thus, there are $p_k(n-k)$ distributions of this type.

Every distribution of $n$ balls into $k$ boxes is of exactly one of these types, and $(1)$ follows immediately. Using it we can easily add a row to the (corrected) table:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n\backslash k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6\\ \hline
0&1\\
1&1&1\\
2&1&1&1\\
3&1&2&1&1\\
4&1&2&2&1&1\\
5&1&3&3&2&1&1\\
6&1&3&4&3&2&1&1
\end{array}$$

The value $p_2(6)=4$, for instance, is obtained as

$$p_{2-1}(6-1)+p_2(6-4)=p_1(5)+p_2(2)=3+1=4\;.$$

Comment: p(n,k) = p(n-1,k-1) + p(n-k,k) This is exactly what I was looking for